# Definition of Discontinuities and example

Tags: calculus, functions

So definition of discontinuity of some function at some point goes like this:
A function $f$ is not continious at point $a$, where $a$ is an element of $D(f)$, if there exists $x$, which is an element of $D(f)$ such that for some $e>0$ (i am simply using e instead of epsilon) and every $d>0$ (d instead of delta), we have $| x - a| < d$ and $| f(x) - f(a)| > e$.

Does this mean that i need to show that there exists at least one $e>0$, such that for any $d>0$ i have one same x so that i have that $| x - a| < d$ and $| f(x) - f(a)| > e$.

Or does it mean that i need to show that there exists at least one $e>0$, such that for any $d>0$ i have some $x$ where $x$ doesn't have to be the same for all cases of $d$, so that i have $| x - a| < d$ and $| f(x) - f(a)| > e$.

Which one of those two.

Let $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is an element of $Q$  and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is an element of $R-Q$.
So for example if $x=2$ then $f(x)=x$ or if $x=e$ then $f(x)=x^2$. So i need to prove that functions is discontinuous at $x=2$.

So if let $a=2$ and let $x$ be an element form $Q$. Then i have $| x - 2| < d$ and $| x - 2| > e$. This is where i ran into problem. If i let $e=0.001$. Then i can prove that function is discontinuous for all $d > 0.001$ but not for $d = 0.001$ and $d < 0.001$. This happens no matter what. How to solve this?

Comment: ...we have $|x-a|<d$ for **some** $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|> \epsilon$.

Comment: So this means that $x$ depends on $d$?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that smaller $d$ may force the choice of a different $x$. For example, you have have $d_1$ and some $x_1$ such that $|x_1-a| < d_1$. Now let $d_2 = {1 \over 2} |x_1-a|$, then you can see that $x_2$ must be different (closer to $a$).